# Speakers can't connect

Tags: windows-7, speakers

Good morning , recently I bought a pair of speakers for my pc ( Trust Soundforce 2.0 ) , I tried to connect it to the computer , but it is impossible. Practically pc (Windows 7) does not detect it than i can't listen anything ( there aren't message or alerts , i just can't listen anything).The speakers work with an audio jack , my old ones had not any troubles with the same pc.
I tried to connect it to another pc ( Windows 10 ) and there's no problems. What could it be the problem ?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the speakers to another source to make sure they actually work? There's nothing to "detect" on most computers when you're dealing with analog audio hardware (such as speakers that connect by audio jack).

Comment: You say trying to connect them, connect them how? Via usb, bluetooth?

Comment: Audio jack . yes , speakers work with others pc , could be a driver problem ?